# apt-get autoremove doesn't accept regular expressions?

Tags: apt

Running `apt-get install libboost.*1.40.0` (Ubuntu 10.04.4) works perfectly.

But `apt-get autoremove libboost.*1.40.0`... not so much. Any workaround?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting libboost-system1.40.0 for regex 'libboost.*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-python1.40.0 for regex 'libboost.*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-signals1.40.0 for regex 'libboost.*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-program-options1.40.0 for regex 'libboost.*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-date-time1.40.0 for regex 'libboost.*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-test1.40.0 for regex 'libboost.*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-iostreams1.40.0 for regex 'libboost.*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-wave1.40.0 for regex 'libboost.*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-graph1.40.0 for regex 'libboost.*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-thread1.40.0 for regex 'libboost.*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-serialization1.40.0 for regex 'libboost.*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-math1.40.0 for regex 'libboost.*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-regex1.40.0 for regex 'libboost.*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-filesystem1.40.0 for regex 'libboost.*1.40.0'
E: Couldn't find package libboost.*1.40.0
```

Edit: In fact this has nothing to do with `autoremove`, even `remove` will do the same

```
~# apt-get remove libboost-[a-z]*1.40.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note , selecting libboost-system1.40.0 for regex 'libboost-[a-z]*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-python1.40.0 for regex 'libboost-[a-z]*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-signals1.40.0 for regex 'libboost-[a-z]*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-test1.40.0 for regex 'libboost-[a-z]*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-iostreams1.40.0 for regex 'libboost-[a-z]*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-wave1.40.0 for regex 'libboost-[a-z]*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-graph1.40.0 for regex 'libboost-[a-z]*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-thread1.40.0 for regex 'libboost-[a-z]*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-serialization1.40.0 for regex 'libboost-[a-z]*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-math1.40.0 for regex 'libboost-[a-z]*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-regex1.40.0 for regex 'libboost-[a-z]*1.40.0'
Note, selecting libboost-filesystem1.40.0 for regex 'libboost-[a-z]*1.40.0'
E: Couldn't find package libboost-[a-z]*1.40.0
```

Comment: autoremove doesn't take *any* options.  It automatically removes *all* packages that were auto installed and are no longer required.

Comment: @psusi Actually it does. `apt-get autoremove foo` will remove foo along with any pending packages scheduled for auto removal.

Comment: @dobey No, according to the manpage one should use it like this: `apt-get remove --auto-remove pkg`. The commands `check`, `clean`, `autoclean`, `autoremove`, `update`, `upgrade`, `dselect-upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` don't take any package as arguments.

Comment: It seems that either the program is wrong, or the man page is.  Time to file a bug report.

Comment: Actually, even `apt-get remove libboost.*1.40.0` fails with the same error message so it has nothing to do with `autoremove`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you can run `dpkg -l|grep 'libboost.*1.40.0'|cut -d' ' -f3|xargs sudo apt-get remove --purge` to remove them from your system.

Comment: I had to add `-qq` to the `apt-get` command because otherwise it would auto-abort (??) but otherwise thanks!